# Cited and non-cited references

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm writing a document which has both a "References" and a "Further Reading" section via BibTeX. I'd like to be able to put all cited references in the "references" section (using `\bibliography`, of course), and put the remainder of the references in my `.bib` (those which are never cited) in the "Further Reading" section.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please, look at the question linked by Brent; if it solves your problem, let us know with a comment. Otherwise, please add information to your question in order to state why the other one doesn't help.

Comment: It's just 30 mins. What's the rush to close this question?

Comment: Exact duplicate. Not sure how I missed it. Thanks for the help all.